# ActiveRecord: how to destroy object so that its id gets free

Tags: activerecord

I **create** 10 records, I **destroy** 10 records. I **create** another 10 records and now first of those records has the *id* of 11. I want it to automatically be assigned to 1.

How to destroy an object in such a way that its index is gets free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

or

```
rake db:schema:load
```

(just make sure you ran all of your migrations beforehand with `rake db:migrate`) which side effects will include clearing records' ids.